# Formating by creating spaces between Shiny Plots

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to do some formatting for my shiny app. 
There is no space between my plots. Can someone please show me how to create spaces between my plots?
Below is my UI code: My plots are

```
dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(    selectizeInput("group",
                                      label = "group",
                                      choices = unique(dataset$group),
                                      multiple = F,
                                      options = list(maxItems = 5, placeholder = 'Please select a group(s)'),
                                      selected = "None")),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      plotlyOutput("plot1"),
      plotlyOutput("plot2"),
      plotlyOutput("plot3"),
      plotlyOutput("plot4")
    )
  )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to style your pages. There are quite a few options described [here](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html).

You can use one of them to add, say, [`margin`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) around your plots.

Comment: Good suggestion. Thank you.